# Keep two <select>s in sync

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<select>`s in my app but on different screens. They have the same `change` handler attached to them and have the same values. When one changes the other should change its value accordingly.

The problem is when one is changed and I try to change the other, it will fire the `change` event on the first one and so on recursively.

So how do I change a select, but not fire a change event?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "different screens" ?

Comment: It's a jquery mobile app, the selects appear on dofferent screens, but they are in the same document.

Comment: Although this is a solved problem, for those interested if the above was actually the issue, you'd get this site's namesake, whereas if it's a regular loop causing the issue it would just hang.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> when I try to change the other, it will fire the change event on the first one and so on recursively.

Really? You must be doing something wrong then, usually changing the value does not fire the event. Just use

```
var bothselects = $("#first-select, #second-select");
bothselects.change(function(e) {
    bothselects.val(this.value); // "this" is the changed one

    // do whatever else you need to do
});
```

Comment: Actually that was another loop inside the handler that caused the problem for me. Thanks for proving the event doesn't fire on programmatic change.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match option for option by index, not value, then do so as follows :

HTML :

```
<select class="synch">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select class="synch">
  <option value="AA">AA</option>
  <option value="BB">BB</option>
  <option value="CC">CC</option>
</select>
```

javascript :

```
var $synch = $(".synch").on('change', function() {
  $synch.not(this).get(0).selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kdsak/1/)**

I can't see that recursion should be a problem. Even if changing a `<select>` programatically did fire the 'change' event (which it doesn't) then after the first synchronization, the two indexes (or values) would match and no further change would happen, nor need to happen. Therefore no change, no change event, and no recursion.

Comment: Really, the problem was another loop in my code. Youare correct that the event doesn't fire the second time, but Bergi said that first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $selects=$('#select_1,#select_2').change(function(){
    $selects.not(this).val( $(this).val() );
})
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mGYGK/

Comment: Thanks for the idea to remember selects in a var first! But actually the check for `.not(this)` does nothing.

Comment: sure it does... when you manually change select, no point in changing it's value with script again...it was just changed. Only need script to change the other one

Comment: It seems that the overhead of checking for .not() does actually more work than setting the same value twice.

Comment: Moreover as we've discovered setting the value will not fire the event again. Nor would it if we selected the same option with a click.

Comment: lost me on that one.... if an option is already selected there is no `change` , however to make 2 selects match on page load can trigger a change

Comment: `overhead`?  not sure where you got that idea from... perf test shows `not` significantly faster  http://jsperf.com/2-selects-chnage-value

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
  $("#select2").val($("#select1").val())
});
$("#select2").change(function(){
  $("#select1").val($("#select2").val())
});
```

You can view a live demo of this function [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fBHRb/2/)

Comment: a lot simpler using `val()`   you just weren't using it properly before

Answer (score 0):

In the change handler, update the other select only if its value is different, do nothing if the values match. This breaks recursion.