# JavaScript - Select an option in optgroup from other dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, dom

have been googling around but no result. So, I have this problem on constructing a js scipt to automatically choose an option from optgroup from another dropdown menu.

So, it will look like:

Drop-Down Menu

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">A*</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#">C</a></li>
<li><a href="#">D</a></li></ul>
```

So above is list of grades and supposedly choose the specific option from optgroup. Below is the optgroup in html.

```
<optgroup label="Grade Comments">
<option value="Category 1">Comment for A*</option>
<option value="Category 2">Comment for A</option>
<option value="Category 3">Comment for B</option>
<option value="Category 4">Comment for C</option>
<option value="Category 5">Comment for D</option></optgroup>
```

So when the user certain grade, the specific comment will be chosen. How can I bind the grade and the comment?

Comment: please share what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, sorry, i actually am very new in javascript/html and no idea where to start. Can gv me any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the below code.

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="category">
    <li><a href="#">A*</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">D</a></li></ul>

    <select id="selectCmt">
    <optgroup label="Grade Comments">
    <option value="A*">Comment for A*</option>
    <option value="A">Comment for A</option>
    <option value="B">Comment for B</option>
    <option value="C">Comment for C</option>
    <option value="D">Comment for D</option></optgroup>
    </select>
```

js :

```
    $("#category").on("click","a",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#selectCmt').val($(this).text());
    })
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Ms49j/

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that another user asked this question quite a while ago.
Please have a look at: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268685/keep-two-selects-in-sync).

Try to understand the help. Aju Mon is right. Just copy&paste isn't the right way to solve problems.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with advanced browser only: http://jsfiddle.net/Eqwst/
and with `<select id="myselect">...</select>`

```
var select = document.getElementById('myselect');
function fselect(index, ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    select.value = 'Category ' + index;
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu li a'), function(el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', fselect.bind(el, i+1), false);
})
```